# OpenModelica HeatingSystem

Tags: debugging, simulation, modelica, openmodelica

I am looking into openmodelica and therefore I am recreating examples from the standard library.

Under Modelica > Fluid > Examples there is the HeatingSystem model which I recreated and the simulation fails due to division by zero. The original one from the library also fails.

I have two questions:

1. is it just me, or is it a buggy example?
2. If it is not me: Can somebody help me resolve the issue using the debugger, which confuses me very much?

I am running the latest nighly (since the fedora repo only offers nightlies..) with MSL 4.0.0

Comment: OpenModelica has some issues with some of the models. We are working at fixing these issues but it will take some time. You can see the library coverage here to find out which models are working or not: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/wiki/Library-Coverage-Testing

Comment: thx, I am not quite sure how to interpret the table, but I will now skip examples that are not all green. 
Is there any chance one could debug this using the debugger?

Comment: The debugger can be used to understand how the compiler manipulates your equations to solve the system but if the compiler did something problematic the debugger cannot tell you that. We do use the debugger to understand what the compiler did and sometimes we do find issues in the compiler that way, but is not that usual.